# How to change eclipse line number background color?

Tags: eclipse, line, settings, preferences

Here is what I see in eclipse when looking at line numbers:

[Link to picture on stack.imgur - did not allow for picture upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkFIz.png)

Is there a way to change it so there is a black background for the numbers, i.e. having black background and white line numbers instead of white numbers on gray background?

Please notice it is hard to see white numbers. I am trying to go all black since it is easier on my eyes.

Comment: That does not look like the standard dark theme of the current Eclipse IDE. Please upgrade.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and which dark theme are you using? With the lastest release of Eclipse and the "Dev Style / Darkest dark" I have no such problems. See: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle